linking gcc compiled c application to c and gfortran libraries
I am trying to link an application compiled with gcc 8.5.0 to c and Fortran libraries compiled with gcc 8.5.0 and gfortran (version unknown) on Oracle Linux (a RedHat derivative). Linking to the gcc compiled library works just fine, so I will omit details. Linking the C application to the Fortran library gives me undefined references, however. The issue seems to be with a trailing/appended underscore in the exported symbols of the Fortran library. I have no control over the Fortran library.
My C code calls the Fortran symbols as so:
foo_c_app.exe:
foo_fortran_routine(x, y, z);

If I change the calls to:
foo_fortran_routine_(x, y, z);

Linking works without error. All of the code is considered legacy and worked in the past with simple compiler options. I would like to not change the code to get it to compile and link without error, as was done before, is it possible, if so how?
Also, when I execute nm on the Fortran library, I get:
T foo_fortran_routine_

Thus far, I have tried using gcc and gfortran for linking with various options, but nothing has worked. The only thing that works is adding the trailing underscore to the function calls in the C code, which is not ideal in my opinion.

You can play different tricks with objcopy, for example redefine the symbols with trailing underscore to ones without as in objcopy --redefine-sym old=new

You could also use a linker script that would define new symbols to alias the old ones

Or just write a little wrapper library

@EugeneSh. the last one is the best

Did the calls that used to work indeed work with the same Fortran library binary -- or has the library bee recompiled/updated? Because I see that the Fortran compiler g77 has -fno-underscoring which must be set to prevent them. Recompilation without that option (which was present for the old libraries) would explain that you cannot link anymore code which you used to. If that is so, you can perhaps convince the distributor to produce a compatible library. Conceivably, you have one that is meant to be linked against regular Fortran programs!

Have you consulted the documentation that comes with gfortran?  It clearly describes the options that you may or may not need.

Does the Fortran library already come to you compiled or what does the "no control" mean? If you only have control over the C code and the symbols you have do have and underscore, you do need the underscore. If you can compile the Fortran code differently, follow the suggestion by Peter and steve.
